# How do I combine the vc-bundle, Arara, and Sublime Text 2's build methods?

Tags: arara, git

**Note:** This question is about getting Arara and the vc-bundle to work with a Sublime Text 2 build method.

I write my papers with [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com), and I use [Git](http://git-scm.com) for version control. I use the [vc-bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/vc) to give me access to information from Git. In order to make calling the scripts easier I use [Arara](http://cereda.github.io/arara/) as my automation tool. I have the following in my working directory.

- araravcmwe.tex
- vc (the Git version of the script from vc-bundle)
- vc-git.awk
- A Git repo with at least one commit

The .tex file looks like this.

```
% arara: vc
% arara: xelatexmk: {synctex: true, options: '-pv'}
\documentclass{memoir}

\input{vc.tex}

\title{Title}
\date{\VCDateISO}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some words.
\end{document}
```

I also have an Arara rule that looks like this.

```
!config
identifier: vc
name: VC
command: sh vc
arguments: []
```

It's saved as 'vc.yaml' somewhere Arara can see it i.e. in the path set in my araraconfig.yaml. That all works. I can do `$ arara araravcmwe` and get a PDF with the date of the last commit where I want it. So, this isn't a problem with the way I've set up the vc-bundle or Arara.

My problem is with my Sublime Text 2 build method. I tried the following, saved as 'Arara.sublime-build' in Packages/User/.

```
{   "cmd": ["arara",
            "$file"],

    "path": "$PATH:/usr/texbin",

    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]+): ([0-9]*)([^\\.]+)"
}
```

That also seems to work, except for my vc rule. When I use the method the vc.tex file is generated, but it's blank. (Therefore \VCDateISO is undefined and the file won't compile.) The xelatexmk directive that comes with Arara works fine with the build method; the problem is something specific to the vc rule. My first thought is that somehow the build method doesn't 'see' vc-git.awk. But that could be completely wrong.